# How to get the current record No. from foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

This is my current code:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Race</td>
        <td>Nationality</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach($datas as $data)
    <tr>
        <td>$number++</td>
        <td>{{ $data->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->gender }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->race }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->nationality }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

As you can see, how do I put the No. of record inside the field ($number++)?
Obviously for current code, it will throw an error, but I'm just showing you guys what I want.

Comment: You need to reformat your code to use proper indenting.

Comment: instead of $number++ use {{ ($number++) }}

Answer (score 1):

you this code

```
   <td>

       {{$number++}}

            </td>
```

you can also use first increase number value then echo it

```
$number++;
```

{{$number}}

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `$loop` variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable), this can get you all sorts of information about the loop including the current iteration.

```
<td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If this solved your problem, consider marking this as the answer to you question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key like index/counter

```
 <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>Race</td>
        <td>Nationality</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach($datas as $key => $data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$key}}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->gender }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->race }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->nationality }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: There is no way to be sure that the keys will contain the correct numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by correct numbers.
`$key` is the index in a php array that begins by 0.
if you are looking for ID of record you can get it from database `$data->id`.

Comment: If you reordered the array or you have an array that has strings as keys. In these cases the first `$key` would most likely not be `0`